# Flask Mail sending plain text only

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I am sending emails with flask-mail but the email is received like a plain text, excluding the html formats and images.
I can't figure out what's wrong with the code.

Here is the send mail method:

```
def send_async_email(app, msg):
with app.app_context():
    mail.send(msg)

def send_email(to, subject, template, **kwargs):
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    msg = Message(app.config['MAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX'] + ' ' + subject, sender=app.config['MAIL_SENDER'], recipients=[to])
    msg.body = render_template(template + '.txt', **kwargs)
    msg.html = render_template(template + '.html', **kwargs)
    thr = Thread(target=send_async_email, args=[app, msg])
    thr.start()
    return thr
```

This is the view function that sends the email:

```
@main.route('/confirm', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def confirm():
    send_email(current_user.email, 'Confirm Your Account', 'auth/email/confirm', user=current_user)
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">


<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='toolkit.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='application.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap-formhelpers.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.min.js') }}"></script>

<style>
  /* note: this is a hack for ios iframe for bootstrap themes shopify page */
  /* this chunk of css is not part of the toolkit :) */
  body {
    width: 1px;
    min-width: 100%;
    *width: 100%;
  }

.tag-line {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
</style>

</head>
<body class="with-top-navbar">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top app-navbar">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <img height="60" class="lex-brand" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/logo.png') }}" />
</div>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3>Confirm Your Account</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
<ul class="list-group media-list media-list-stream more-posts" id="latest_async">
<li class="post media list-group-item p-a" >
    <div class="media-body">
    <p>Dear {{ user.first_name }}</p>

    <p>
        Thanks for signing up.
    </p>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap-formhelpers.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.min.js') }}">.    </script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='chart.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='toolkit.js') }}">.  </script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='application.js') }}"></script>
<script>
  // execute/clear BS loaders for docs
  $(function(){
    if (window.BS&&window.BS.loader&&window.BS.loader.length) {
      while(BS.loader.length){(BS.loader.pop())()}
    }
  })
</script>
</html>
```

Everything seems to work fine, no problem with sending the emails, the only issues that the email is received as a plain text excluding the images.

Also something to note is that the {{ user.first_name }} is rendered correctly for the current user's first name.

**UPDATE:**
I am running the app on my localhost server on my computer.

```html
**ANOTHER UPDATE**
Here is the new email payload, in my email reader.


Received: from VE1EUR02HT153.eop-EUR02.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2603:10a6:200:42::34) by AM3PR04MB0631.eurprd04.prod.outlook.com with HTTPS
 via AM4PR0701CA0024.EURPRD07.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM; Wed, 22 Nov 2017 08:21:43
 +0000
Received: from VE1EUR02FT048.eop-EUR02.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (10.152.12.59) by VE1EUR02HT153.eop-EUR02.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (10.152.13.169) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id 15.20.218.12; Wed, 22
 Nov 2017 08:21:42 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 104.47.40.68)
 smtp.mailfrom=culturevulturez.net; live.com; dkim=pass (signature was
 verified) header.d=NETORGFT3228599.onmicrosoft.com;live.com;
 dmarc=bestguesspass action=none header.from=culturevulturez.net;
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of culturevulturez.net
 designates 104.47.40.68 as permitted sender) receiver=protection.outlook.com;
 client-ip=104.47.40.68; helo=NAM03-CO1-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com;
Received: from NAM03-CO1-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com (104.47.40.68) by
 VE1EUR02FT048.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.13.177) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id
 15.20.218.12 via Frontend Transport; Wed, 22 Nov 2017 08:21:41 +0000
X-IncomingTopHeaderMarker: OriginalChecksum:8AA3A0EDCBE858018CD19D1B654F99A51ADBF801B33B951ABD552D1E6A130C51;UpperCasedChecksum:A0038C9402854779FF53546EC7A67305BE1D936D520D3C981EC71711B9CCC59F;SizeAsReceived:8459;Count:35
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
 d=NETORGFT3228599.onmicrosoft.com; s=selector1-culturevulturez-net;
 h=From:Date:Subject:Message-ID:Content-Type:MIME-Version;
 bh=RQg6SExDAQoLnLofNp9XG45rLASPhKjdQbC3urnfZ6w=;
 b=hPQUch9ZhTdJNROLP49iU1aoixw09be0a1NxWNqHtiCgU/G9hb8YjvrId8anFbve0kz2+oFllPX0PLjcALJEGVsk5koYiYsF0nQEU/rqI17KDP/q10bCzOH30IorqXSKjVACW5wjyL2m0MA0s4kuUvJcL8Dv3GwHqpVj2JMPl7c=
Authentication-Results-Original: spf=none (sender IP is )
 smtp.mailfrom=alex@culturevulturez.net; 
Received: from Alexs-MacBook-Pro.local (2601:643:8500:8c25::8f8b) by
 DM5PR1601MB1115.namprd16.prod.outlook.com (10.172.86.9) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P256) id
 15.20.239.5; Wed, 22 Nov 2017 08:21:39 +0000
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============4649907699319288713=="
Subject: [C-V] Confirm Your Account
From: alex@culturevulturez.net
To: <hardingalex@live.com>
Date: Wed, 22 Nov 2017 00:21:39 -0800
Message-ID: <151133888472.22575.2423685137359127157@Alexs-MacBook-Pro.local>
X-Originating-IP: [2601:643:8500:8c25::8f8b]
X-ClientProxiedBy: MWHPR17CA0065.namprd17.prod.outlook.com (10.173.106.155) To
 DM5PR1601MB1115.namprd16.prod.outlook.com (10.172.86.9)
Return-Path: alex@culturevulturez.net
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 41343eb9-f351-42cb-160e-08d531820fab
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Untrusted: UriScan:;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(4534020)(4602075)(4603075)(4627115)(201702281549075)(5600022)(4604075)(2017052603258);SRVR:DM5PR1601MB1115;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics-untrusted: 1;DM5PR1601MB1115;3:xx8qFRovQEnfff+/hEe8+AS2f5PKpEHcQ9/4uxCnx1q47cTTOrnO11tLwTGL7hHgVtbqMbRKdZ1VT5t7DymtUT2QTAoxeU9hOhzg6AaVpIzUVImy+fnMDtzRdjoocNHcDJCbpy+9HdyxA/p4nRL9OqWnQlT4ENBhI00zIbnSPEC0kuNdARW0DkVe3oIWhVrnJDon0cXrV+FeC5rG+t4vSLpOLjAnK50N+WFmWSLh3xcfQxlvNgUTm/PMNsy6Vri+;25:InRP2+Mwi0RHvPtz7AfaX40Nfy885MFp/xV4o15XLvku33q4GaYYnyef45utCK+QCHp5ldfFUKHJMTu3fTxzijhl7D9oyv1+xl+s7WA73SDmmbTYXDyq3DlLT4Lz3qlpVYfxq9RPmt8T8czcU9n6p6rE74BMKy/cNn2oRfe3Z787q72kF/9UUB9ZdYUDbJaVyea5aPNjn0Sh73srGJ3pcMcti46xPpIsttIe5z5qvfMTRSzWrpYqw5sjDC505jdDmCChOvhTA4yStjAxvfo5G2LnRS2+jA/MfmqFTv7wGetvBB49A86Qd+ufOJxNsV2JqUf71xFuePrENfSWttlflg==;31:8v+9cWlwPenfxMceQq2S8zTpn2op4pErYgdbXfCkYH5Owp5DKLJboj6KZFkDK7UouZltm73AxOGYcxWDkFzRcjDaqpI6Om2Acr33kQtYf6sojOFPsjmnNXlvAt71qeeJx0z0Z4sKSNV4xZYCsWIANLVr/o/QgmxuhbGRUU7c27jKMnnQUpyzy4tkJh2h/UIakKJeDwmzfgdbZEXS1SPqWjYsNTpoUR/HTXmK6B5A9Os=
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: DM5PR1601MB1115:|VE1EUR02HT153:
X-Microsoft-Antispam-PRVS: <DM5PR1601MB1115EBB1D3A97D1EA11F3F42D4200@DM5PR1601MB1115.namprd16.prod.outlook.com>
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-Test: UriScan:(231181664957973)(227612066756510)(199454328027089);UriScan:(231181664957973)(227612066756510)(199454328027089);
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test: =?us-ascii?Q?BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(100000700101)(100105000095)(100000701101?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?)(100105300095)(100000702101)(100105100095)(6040450)(2401047?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?)(8121501046)(5005006)(3002001)(10201501046)(3231022)(930060?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?95)(93001095)(100000703101)(100105400095)(6041248)(201611235?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?62025)(20161123564025)(2016111802025)(20161123560025)(201611?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?23558100)(20161123555025)(201703131423075)(201702281528075)(?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?201703061421075)(201703061406153)(6043046)(6072148)(20170807?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?1742011)(100000704101)(100105200095)(100000705101)(100105500?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?095);SRVR:DM5PR1601MB1115;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(100000800101)(?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?100110000095)(100000801101)(100110300095)(100000802101)(1001?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?10100095)(100000803101)(100110400095)(100000804101)(10011020?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?0095)(100000805101)(100110500095);SRVR:DM5PR1601MB1115;BCL:0?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?;PCL:0;RULEID:(100000700101)(100105000095)(100000701101)(100?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?105300095)(100000702101)(100105100095)(444111536)(1160499008?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?)(595095)(82015058);SRVR:VE1EUR02HT153;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(1?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?00000800101)(100110000095)(100000801101)(100110300095)(10000?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?0802101)(100110100095)(100000803101)(100110400095)(100000804?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?101)(100110200095)(100000805101)(100110500095);SRVR:VE1EUR02?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?HT153;?=
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics-untrusted: 1;DM5PR1601MB1115;4:QhNqF+0Z7kp1NZ+pGnSBHbMuJ85zmoUBvW91OYM6pp5pJ6k7DOnmTsAQAPs1iOnOG6BBb2ruyhLUBlliXngWhYuC7BQv9nP/jjbnFpH3XkzkVfKRL226EV+mJADPD2NY7UkN7mTipcdbMB3PHzMwb+K/ZpvD0Eih8CqY7KcgbMikDQJg4pq32aDHYdrjUD7nzI3hXYqgvocWmpAKlSfDPIDGtsr2BHTlbNGqE5t60b7Gv2Y71KTsHfplL89sTj75AA8wsEsFnnAwPU1cVE5vVTN4w9ouuJiY69OOv+2wDirUoAD9B66k+NOCnzRvghLS8nxOyrOYrQWXQK73ih+69QDbGYAWeZ5tJ/2uHI1sglYLq3L44gOyxDjbiF8uxbaK
X-Forefront-PRVS: 0499DAF22A
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report-Untrusted: SFV:NSPM;SFS:(10009020)(6019001)(39830400002)(346002)(376002)(279900001)(189002)(199003)(113084005)(2420400007)(16586007)(270700001)(25786009)(39060400002)(5000100001)(2476003)(89386003)(15650500001)(4610100001)(5660300001)(106356001)(100306002)(50986999)(105586002)(54356999)(316002)(345774005)(10126004)(512874002)(2906002)(966005)(7110500001)(19630485002)(606006)(98436002)(6116002)(478600001)(101416001)(10710500007)(6916009)(8936002)(84326002)(2361001)(2351001)(88526003)(86362001)(53936002)(575854001)(19625305001)(189998001)(55016002)(85782001)(733005)(861006)(8676002)(81156014)(81166006)(6306002)(9686003)(7736002)(52396003)(68736007)(97736004)(105646017)(24616003)(85772001)(344275003);DIR:OUT;SFP:1101;SCL:1;SRVR:DM5PR1601MB1115;H:Alexs-MacBook-Pro.local;FPR:;SPF:None;PTR:InfoNoRecords;MX:1;A:1;LANG:en;
Received-SPF: None (protection.outlook.com: culturevulturez.net does not
 designate permitted sender hosts)
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics-untrusted: =?us-ascii?Q?1;DM5PR1601MB1115;23:Oq5dqjbBv1q+EW4GvGFHFhf6ztKoDsNhv6DQoLN?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?vwauL9FZ0tizajWHop2d9V7n5iIsQogYC0zsXGVplLVPI+URHE3sIl1ME/rG?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?wU9PEoryhpvjLajfotRin1QgdkDHwwyIUeAy9ueQIORnO9DHIBJzVgGWaqjw?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?jKiI7RdtdJHOqKvZ4xOYCgAly9ZplkbESTkYPGAokDIf6q32atYpcPcVL+n/?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?mnMZaKP0OLebBReJElFiWCdtdiTtXx/Dbp7KXrpOxdH39cvzwMRnyGFluZaI?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?ELaVPYhto0XKL1ZU1VXbqh/cxg4UU3GGFlshxUNrQygyYSIWI+RpY39fHoMc?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?FvZq4PvANgpM47a6Tn2d6HXA7t+PMig/FyattD10fd3yNCyNZx3Y9m8AIVxH?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?LtY/Onba+GjruyzZoblDKkN8G1rV6dVUe2YIaOV0tlV+iJ0x4FUCLEM+1614?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?hD1ntvG9MppkvLRtZ5oqWr9alA7F8nV7xYTDwu08Z+IIdO7mrvqjfJLK6dh0?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?eSl7nMgQMHjUwECvXljX4TZ6zN3ZaGY6JnCGfnjlySKfNBZm5j8aNZvy/Dum?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?PBCPrnzGcNbaJo3c/qYb+g1bTWxLc/r587uoznor5j5EUGDjt1F3ZgJOBi+U?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?dNzJbA6Vn+BZ76UYD6OZMmCf7SFMGdQz0zQ5F2aId8TxLvuP7lXS7gC2XFjn?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?53ZCCK1vrOtJMgxP69GTAyo4Gc8+VcEocPJteBfElsGVdSgOeh/Fs0xwBchu?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?Iv8BXB+4zgV+CnizgREGndOOq5SwPGRrJ3IsKMCDoo+8RC3CWN06ObSWhjgl?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?59BqpPLairXWD6OG5f/vqa432YTkywB3vyB3a7Js5ZGr9NccVeQ1HCciW+zI?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?8FOkgvvIZR7uocGm4rRHSad0NBCWUuh3CjAVrwnGZVwE6febGW7qtACCM8R1?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?FwLXr4mFMBW/F1Ijpj34ztPjgoDVEacVDvBinXqzon5f6rtIXHdoyYecwBk+?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?KisPbPns/kjkTnnUEBwDXR6O3P05TAvyML6oOj3q+tsBcduLS75TrdhmNDSp?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?WQQL62nZ8arYHMvOWz1ubggJx1XeSS2khm2z0xu1TplP0LUFf0WvDVUqD6X7?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?mNXi30lP3HSeF33ZHfrfBs8k6Din6V71pUYhjctLexBm8UXJiQkq/fTPNpzN?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?Ipl1P6cDn2xCOqRvJXQH7dZrU8U72DpwRhjrkhSRY4oYnhDj6inplmWEpI1d?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?po9M0UxHtjeVEW07qUu4o/xtha0FtQKdmiI3Ck+RYTdH9XqW0nSoYfmnkTuz?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?L1eD7IDCIp05v97b2xAr65XNBY0l6Gx5cm+jJzsRfs909OYqS2j9bzlVZ6vp?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?iCgmWryqmt6MiHkUg/3Wb74qu2z1qwRlGC4eEW/4nKPlm3vg3Y6zw3vfHuOu?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?jjQDy5V1dJFEx81xzw7zYXw7w1kk4OnWzGYPqhQsGFs1DcUacYl7aT6tacS2?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?+lrW7gT02XitVdhumMr4fHtDm+/+/EK2/4Y6eqrIjk63ciUql2mV/NeEQK/L?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?q7nq6ECy/4pLefkxRIw=3D=3D?=
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics-untrusted: 1;DM5PR1601MB1115;6:OTNLzCRNuDX8pl7uhfBZt/XbBMcOxZdijsL0mq+ccRjg9snY+R6/Sb2v76FCzLF2vOQ2p1Oj7Ws3LcYLEDvsl7mR7E///6d2rpiYDXGJH17zEO4UnK4YQaQzLJCdV75+L9PCHApNRnVMTYNnLnYO+HCXH/l5BNGe//uzKBQFgDtO0N2ZzUVdo3dTEyi1KsIHiRqkTjXD0UnDgLCJ/yZ8hc1NYMEOPdojfXEEGd6+vm0jxPg4b5VvKgF9z2hAMnH+4UmRYOZE8KDwE8k27HJeM0u8uoCoC2fkqrCmyVL5TuJ8OS/e01MP9Eb4m/8LNEmWOYwiQ+z0rCS3vTDI5y0tbGM6CLo9C2UxGAzzPi4Dihg=;5:FWqorge/YbXzx2PALaRQ50hIl7n6GHNzUDtpALp+XX9GeQomwt3c2fQsYVtjT+qMeFi6qk9lESc9/m2MCk9Vdec+UiuweidCKfrsXn1Bp9Pe2tvOlP089H+83koHMWk3fCYHlMMLP+eYVPdr9uKl3OYZDAXpzU/bt3aEouA6+WE=;24:GGhTEjibxi5jQH/Z/PR54bR+QCWNaXVXB9reBdJvw1R3S7jy9h2FuqqfxUD+xpJGq9nTTQKkb46Jq5ijIvrLffb6Ox1hF9U8GegW7h7ivp4=;7:vI7N3RcCjRUk50bdR/ikCubLuVVmjlXsa8AKrUhEtqG4WjFKRirCEqd2s76UWOmLQjejThf4ere7tnHOhxpbu1OjUVL4tcQcOE4GE+pYcX+khJI7zOCQzMk+qvHPzd0xraMC95+L3rCTinTJIloj7w8ssTlS7NjYn+gX9UIlbMCotIEFeA5CeGVlIagZy1MFuZ89J9mw3epg0+wa9EfIDi6zwmGrfm9HOvhhQ0VzGm45Y8buqwRHwDV95yuDrEWS
SpamDiagnosticOutput: 1:99
SpamDiagnosticMetadata: NSPM
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: DM5PR1601MB1115
X-IncomingHeaderCount: 35
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id: 41343eb9-f351-42cb-160e-08d531820fab
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStripped: VE1EUR02FT048.eop-EUR02.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;VE1EUR02FT048;1:6ZA0Y/IXDulLK6y4r/E2Vcl7XAGsgSynDnSPEH3LJD624BQ/j23envbVnBOq6XIIG5mtbHWfUbN39DL9P2qK9k6ILl68jVaip7SQekT5We5b8Y3NgU3f1KFYHlQbOI47
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: EFV:NLI;SFV:NSPM;SFS:(98901004);DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:1;SRVR:VE1EUR02HT153;H:NAM03-CO1-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com;FPR:;SPF:None;LANG:;
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: VE1EUR02FT048.eop-EUR02.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(5000106)(4604075)(4605076)(610169)(650170)(8291501071);SRVR:VE1EUR02HT153;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;VE1EUR02HT153;3:g/nSeHrKDJuWYWmLKO6TVcEvCSQCYgMcaNGtwAlL0PF8Jn3JMNWkOfwsMlpW+vd4ngTJAWIsn/vfPyiOCOGfXW12TBVi7A9agdc66O4/yg5ESHubC0mnhU3RkxA9lwijZDJCL07/vUHzaZBVMt5cS1r8B1SRxQ3QDMzTxXnoxnAtbcBPYu6vDYoMQfjbg5lWAbBFhIE6qMSw0t0aS0C8hajV+W8B5Kms2oNI2xXp7sSCy9Tb3dYV5NqWBN3EMqKYBjZBpwa+H1dE1EcRiFL3ySVrb/tc1gzjNeEFlOgrKJ0alt87y12BA3kNCas/0fOM;25:W5nhaPEIg/mEJlUelpKxmPRZxoS2m+2D92qtcUWnlFVPvKbcjm71S2HW4SL1gDyatbh6G+IvuwUsejPy4lcSWsuKk+QeL9TsL6BuqAuODfXl/tugmLRQZ+58/gVb20aj+nzmAPNTfnflKNFNtdzq7P+SpXbCx4LUdN4A73aQcRpoZWvDWKOHrDVt9WawOPkBrRWtO975K47eMUVEQDaU2crzHXGACnaU7nhCRlXRXGEmgDhKvMv0d+0LFPN4djqODUBuGJoeVibtm4BILdl4oyKkxSwECuUdODemURXKx9IhT4aNuhl8nOR/C/b0cY93g6SVCwkg7RY52jlPwBK3Ow==;31:RuzkureFJPjR4B7c6XW/J9g2kL0bccYA8vJ9PRlNR7bjXRBoHCTocRQUuqPYq66SYY05y/Kpg5gSFTpRi+NnssosmFwHo1vc7L9UdoMivIxCU1Qugjr3lttUc4byTpr8YARotxUlVDalu8nRQ20YzTCdSJ3Diqn8lQFxnN3OxMN7sFbN/QPSz25XmsFgybAdWby74yX2kwJKPbun0l5xlTnwyIGYZDJWUzWLLLeo7DU=
X-MS-Exchange-EOPDirect: true
X-Sender-IP: 104.47.40.68
X-SID-PRA: ALEX@CULTUREVULTUREZ.NET
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 4
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;VE1EUR02HT153;4:KW6wz8OC1eTKYm2bfAqlRmeNRJLXi9PcV3u8ewkc2HYwD6EDTVCQt/7Buqb1eIUkoVVgmSeOhqYWoI0OWMGKRuFSrRRwxWgNt+glEA9/HcH3NuPDC3CJ389S7MxL8fCG/9xq3NGTuFWoYscQDVlbaKUtcIPTg11AhSbhSRNzMJ5+pY+SwWLqJFQhglQj+TO/4bgm79odpO8GQQLg8v63T4jvvHBP9AVwqoSPVnmKTiLbInqM7IES7Gl8PmYvVcO5WXEtGLjsygsMI4d6Jsr1ceOiUqd/LBe8wJz+OnB7h346EqGyLrhkFbCLzhqBCzYzpruxTWCIolrTryl4Bt+MnmzusVilEK9pP6U3HXgm5OA+/8d7pYn4KTqtYjdxDnFo;23:Y6cxobX20To4gCovd1DAc/GXtr8p2x8g0cHl6dY/qLd1U+EIzuLE/0cvWSRU5+P+Xa98pt1otX5YxIy5Oq7CzoMn7XgOPs0jRa9egIxssX/Q68K2tZYfN8GwvsoeAN7VN1Iy3e9xEU8RgEvEqzy3/NcEC/RkTakQrAprAKuq/us=;6:KaDcmdcx8krPC0izL2Viyp/jqhlpVb1YZGYS7zt9l5GTl4tRWQFMfiXLErzyd+z7orUKMTbez/Rx//iZrpBZIwicrDaxMF7SsDIzKTWezjPD2yrzi1iPiXkD6wNq7T7BAl4buGo8O7rKaGrGZMmXYeLEQEGwjhAliIs+di8/EaGWwK44qoAud1plakani/O0Z0hgDSbC/efvWLPXhWQubpyqdIeMgscgGGclwKaVVPUYJ3hZLC+k1zR59co7Dq0yX1KtEaaNZqshTexVE080T0qWErnAs6Ti6Ig9UYP+h2W9Gkqfs1YH3mLAcR/oGdkR2wp6c7A29/v3V93mu3RKVF7WXt/fwSG1vkCYKhhJ/d8=
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 1
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;VE1EUR02HT153;5:BfWMXzYYiw9DggRGC3CrPN4Nei8af28LyeDM/j3mQP0/teLtjskknN9C80wX3tsGCdctR4cr8lDH6wTKe/pAC13RDH/nwDiUqWtwItMDreCjjAWynxiMuh8eyupxocDPRS7U3NMLjiiXFnr1PiywhMQcc1MKSeHSatAmkRXOLYA=;24:UhlHO3iXDt0s9i7P44qAQ8AWwxiH4uQC94NVQ/nUbatkXUdC5rXVKPMojKcHglfu6JKcDoYIGoPDiJG/375BGvOa8Hm4J/eD9C7wn2uCqPI=;7:7y1KqmHUxPQTfV1/tzNTLZkQaNcwN234LKjdotYQCRlpmOuZrRbDn0IJNiHts5W9mkytvEnRDPNR06ITsbf7VyAnSqO3Gb16ktGclcyfo6fhlO0R5Bt7JcQXF6lQI1KeZUQzNC5m12uvr1+kKlJi+g58Yiaduc05a8ta3iW4JAzTxJJhOh6DmFO3R3rafVznG8ZABGeNqKZgw9hhjxSCCVw4HnLvyCNpGZSmGabHSNC4/vc9YLKU/IGrb4I/7s90
X-OriginatorOrg: outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 22 Nov 2017 08:21:41.7110
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: 41343eb9-f351-42cb-160e-08d531820fab
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: VE1EUR02HT153
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:01.9555737
X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.0239.006
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
 1;AM3PR04MB0631;27:6Jfg4yjZchGQJ/YqD0YT11uc9Jg6w1erdtfwqx7/P+5tIxjoNTgz5amkryWnFDyGKX4iMNC80QF90PtVAUjzEYFIiMWFV4vFXuXYgXVXA3Bb8Yf9UNGpL/d05oRs7bV/
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
 abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;ijl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:I;ENG:(400001000128)(400125000095)(5062000261)(5061607266)(5061608174)(4900095)(4920089)(6510075)(4950112)(4990090)(400001001318)(400125100095)(61617190)(400001002128)(400125200095);
X-Message-Info:
 5vMbyqxGkdeLoVYoj9lbpa+EL1LVrKl304nxuRCHfYhjKxJ2fD8i8s22CfWTS95Xn9TJWD1jHuFuuEGFtihPr3I2Hl0UJ5RXdXps6LxEjPmzk3tyOsaQxJeblFMUK8lJACpVcEx6MTXmmouFI6G8GaKZK9MskZLZ7oHiv4MN+bX5Ux8Tr+543qSZa62NaC9sk+MqJMOReYV1RP3yj3afXg==
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MTtHRD0yO1NDTD0z
MIME-Version: 1.0

--===============4649907699319288713==
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="===============5040341289868891612=="
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
 1;AM3PR04MB0631;27:6Jfg4yjZchGQJ/YqD0YT11uc9Jg6w1erdtfwqx7/P+5tIxjoNTgz5amkryWnFDyGKX4iMNC80QF90PtVAUjzEYFIiMWFV4vFXuXYgXVXA3Bb8Yf9UNGpL/d05oRs7bV/
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
 abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;ijl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:I;ENG:(400001000128)(400125000095)(5062000261)(5061607266)(5061608174)(4900095)(4920089)(6510075)(4950112)(4990090)(400001001318)(400125100095)(61617190)(400001002128)(400125200095);
X-Message-Info:
 5vMbyqxGkdeLoVYoj9lbpa+EL1LVrKl304nxuRCHfYhjKxJ2fD8i8s22CfWTS95Xn9TJWD1jHuFuuEGFtihPr3I2Hl0UJ5RXdXps6LxEjPmzk3tyOsaQxJeblFMUK8lJACpVcEx6MTXmmouFI6G8GaKZK9MskZLZ7oHiv4MN+bX5Ux8Tr+543qSZa62NaC9sk+MqJMOReYV1RP3yj3afXg==
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MTtHRD0yO1NDTD0z

--===============5040341289868891612==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
 1;AM3PR04MB0631;27:6Jfg4yjZchGQJ/YqD0YT11uc9Jg6w1erdtfwqx7/P+5tIxjoNTgz5amkryWnFDyGKX4iMNC80QF90PtVAUjzEYFIiMWFV4vFXuXYgXVXA3Bb8Yf9UNGpL/d05oRs7bV/
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
 abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;ijl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:I;ENG:(400001000128)(400125000095)(5062000261)(5061607266)(5061608174)(4900095)(4920089)(6510075)(4950112)(4990090)(400001001318)(400125100095)(61617190)(400001002128)(400125200095);
X-Message-Info:
 5vMbyqxGkdeLoVYoj9lbpa+EL1LVrKl304nxuRCHfYhjKxJ2fD8i8s22CfWTS95Xn9TJWD1jHuFuuEGFtihPr3I2Hl0UJ5RXdXps6LxEjPmzk3tyOsaQxJeblFMUK8lJACpVcEx6MTXmmouFI6G8GaKZK9MskZLZ7oHiv4MN+bX5Ux8Tr+543qSZa62NaC9sk+MqJMOReYV1RP3yj3afXg==
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MTtHRD0yO1NDTD0z

Dear Alex

Thank you for joining the Culture Vulturez community!

Please confirm your account by clicking the link below:

http://127.0.0.1:5000/confirm/123456

Sincerely,

The Culture Vulturez Team!
--===============5040341289868891612==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
 1;AM3PR04MB0631;27:6Jfg4yjZchGQJ/YqD0YT11uc9Jg6w1erdtfwqx7/P+5tIxjoNTgz5amkryWnFDyGKX4iMNC80QF90PtVAUjzEYFIiMWFV4vFXuXYgXVXA3Bb8Yf9UNGpL/d05oRs7bV/
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
 abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;ijl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:I;ENG:(400001000128)(400125000095)(5062000261)(5061607266)(5061608174)(4900095)(4920089)(6510075)(4950112)(4990090)(400001001318)(400125100095)(61617190)(400001002128)(400125200095);
X-Message-Info:
 5vMbyqxGkdeLoVYoj9lbpa+EL1LVrKl304nxuRCHfYhjKxJ2fD8i8s22CfWTS95Xn9TJWD1jHuFuuEGFtihPr3I2Hl0UJ5RXdXps6LxEjPmzk3tyOsaQxJeblFMUK8lJACpVcEx6MTXmmouFI6G8GaKZK9MskZLZ7oHiv4MN+bX5Ux8Tr+543qSZa62NaC9sk+MqJMOReYV1RP3yj3afXg==
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MTtHRD0yO1NDTD0z


    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open&#43;Sans:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/static/toolkit.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/application.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/bootstrap-formhelpers.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/static/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      /* note: this is a hack for ios iframe for bootstrap themes shopify page */
      /* this chunk of css is not part of the toolkit :) */
      body {
        width: 1px;
        min-width: 100%;
        *width: 100%;
      }

    .tag-line {
        color: #ffffff !important;
    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body class="with-top-navbar">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top app-navbar">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <img height="60" class="lex-brand" src="/static/img/logo.png">
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="text-danger">Confirm Your Account</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <img height="60" class="lex-brand" src="/static/img/logo.png">
    <ul class="list-group media-list media-list-stream">
    <li class="post media list-group-item p-a">
        <div class="media-body">
        <p>Dear Alex</p>

        <p>Thank you for joining the Culture Vulturez community!<br>
            Please confirm your account by clicking the link below:<br>
            http://127.0.0.1:5000/confirm/123456<br>

            Sincerely,<br>

            The Culture Vulturez Team!

        </p>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    <script src="/static/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/bootstrap-formhelpers.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/toolkit.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/application.js"></script>
    <script>
      // execute/clear BS loaders for docs
      $(function(){
        if (window.BS&&window.BS.loader&&window.BS.loader.length) {
          while(BS.loader.length){(BS.loader.pop())()}
        }
      })
    </script>
    </html>
    --===============5040341289868891612==--

    --===============4649907699319288713==--
```

Comment: Have you looked at the source data for your email? You might want to add that to the question.

Comment: @Miguel I am not clear on what you mean by "source data for your email" can you please clarify? Thank you

Comment: In your email reader, look for an option that shows you the raw email payload.

Comment: @Miguel by "email reader", do you mean e.g. the macOS mail client?

Comment: Sure, whatever you used to read that email.

Comment: @Miguel I have added it, I had trouble adding it directly in the question so I added it as a snippet. It's quite long.

Comment: And you see that the HTML is in there, right? If you are not seeing the HTML, it must be a problem with your email reader, not a problem with Flask-Mail or your application.

Comment: @Miguel OK, thanks for the insight, I will further look into the reader

Comment: @Miguel I was missing the _external=True argument in the "src" for scripts and stylesheets. It is working now. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I figured it out. all I needed to do was add _external=True in the url_for in the "src" for the scripts and stylesheets.
For example:
Before:`

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js') }}"></script>
```

After:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js', _external=True) }}"></script>
```

Notice the difference?
This should be done for all links in the template.